# Thickbox problem - appearing at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, thickbox

I have a PHP page, in Wordpress.  When I add a inline Thickbox to the page and attempt to open it, the Thickbox opens at the very bottom of the page, after the footer.

Strangely, I took the generated HTML code, and made an HTML file with it.  That HTML file opens the Thickbox correctly.  The only difference is that it is not being generated by wordpress.  The links to JS scripts and everything are identical.

Anyone able to shed on light into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an old source of Thickbox.  I tried uploading the lastest version, imported that one instead, and all is working.
Yay.